# why the ListView can't show currently in react native after i change the value?

Tags: listview, react-native

[image]

This is I used to judge the location of the code

```
<TouchableOpacity
     style={styles.listItem}>
     {
          (rowData.name == 'Abigale') ? 
              <View style={styles.self}>
                <Text>
                  {rowData.msg}:{rowData.name}
                </Text>
              </View>   : 
              <View style={styles.friend}>
                <Text>
                  {rowData.name}:{rowData.msg}
                </Text>
              </View>  
       }
  </TouchableOpacity>
```

This is I used to change the code list

```
this.setState({ dataSource: this.state.dataSource.cloneWithRows(window.abigale.msgList) })
```

why out-of-order when I change the list View?

but if i change the code as this:

```
    <TouchableOpacity style={styles.listItem}>                    
           <Text>{rowData.msg}:{rowData.name}</Text> 
      </TouchableOpacity>
```

the order is right

Answer (score 0):

What you are doing right now is replacing your your old data source with the new one. Instead, you need to append your previous datasource to the new one. So something like this:

```
this.setState({ 
  dataSource: this.state.dataSource
    .cloneWithRows([...this.state.dataSource, ...window.abigale.msgList]) 
})
```